# Strsep returns a 32 bit pointer on my Mac OS X x86_64 system

Tags: c, macos, assembly, 32bit-64bit, x86-64

Edit: Found solution (see bottom)

I'm trying to build a software package ([owfs](http://owfs.org/)) on a Mac OS X 10.8 x86_64 system. This software package is mostly developed on/for linux, but I've gotten an old version to compile and function correctly, and there are plenty of posts around the internet of people running various versions of it, so I'm hopeful that it's possible. I've been able to get the compilation process to complete successfully, but the program segfaults when I try to run it. I investigated in GDB, and here is what I found:

The offending piece of code:

```
void FS_dir_entry_aliased(void (*dirfunc) (void *, const struct parsedname *), void *v, const struct parsedname *pn)
{
if ( ( pn->state & ePS_unaliased ) == 0 ) {
    // Want alias substituted
    struct parsedname s_pn_copy ;
    struct parsedname * pn_copy = & s_pn_copy ;

    ASCII path[PATH_MAX+3] ;
    ASCII * path_pointer = path ; // current location in original path

    // Shallow copy
    memcpy( pn_copy, pn, sizeof(struct parsedname) ) ;
    pn_copy->path[0] = '\0' ;

    // path copy to use for separation
    strcpy( path, pn->path ) ;

    // copy segments of path (delimitted by "/") to copy
    while( path_pointer != NULL ) {
                    ASCII * path_segment = NULL;
        path_segment = strsep( &path_pointer, "/" ) ;
        BYTE sn[SERIAL_NUMBER_SIZE] ;

        if ( PATH_MAX < strlen(pn_copy->path) + strlen(path_segment) ) {
```

The call to `strlen(path_segment)` in the `if` block fails because `path_segment` is an out-of-bounds address.

Taking things step by step with GDB, here's what I've found. Going into the call that initializes `path_segment` with `strsep`, gdb gives me:

```
path_pointer = (ASCII *) 0x7fff5fbf99a5 "/uncached/bus.0/interface"
```

After I execute the next line, `path_pointer` has advanced, as I would expect:

```
path_pointer = (ASCII *) 0x7fff5fbf99a6 "uncached/bus.0/interface"
```

but gdb reports:

```
path_segment = (ASCII *) 0x5fbf99a5 <Address 0x5fbf99a5 out of bounds>
```

This is the correct "start" of the address, but it's a 32-bit pointer address. Since my system is a 64-bit system, when `strlen` gets called on this, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I understand there's a lot going on here, and I haven't provided enough info if the problem is something buried deeply in the package build process. It seems to me though that this might have a simple solution, since the function is basically working correctly, but just returning the wrong size pointer. I have very little experience with the intricacies of 64 bit vs. 32 bit systems though, so I was wondering if anyone can spot something obvious, or provide instructions for next steps debugging this issue. Interestingly, when I run the `strsep` commands by hand in gdb (`p (ASCII *) strsep (&path_pointer, "/")`), they appear to work fine, giving me 64 bit pointers that match what I expect them to.

Finally, in case it's useful, here's what I *believe* are the assembly lines for the strsep call:

```
0x0000000100036eee <FS_dir_entry_aliased+318>:  callq  0x1000a56a0 <dyld_stub_strsep>
0x0000000100036ef3 <FS_dir_entry_aliased+323>:  mov    %eax,%ecx
0x0000000100036ef5 <FS_dir_entry_aliased+325>:  movslq %ecx,%rcx
0x0000000100036ef8 <FS_dir_entry_aliased+328>:  mov    %rcx,-0x1d10(%rbp)
```

and the disassemble for the strsep that's at that callq address:

```
0x00007fff915c0fc7 <strsep+0>:  push   %rbp
0x00007fff915c0fc8 <strsep+1>:  mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x00007fff915c0fcb <strsep+4>:  mov    (%rdi),%r8
0x00007fff915c0fce <strsep+7>:  xor    %eax,%eax
0x00007fff915c0fd0 <strsep+9>:  test   %r8,%r8
0x00007fff915c0fd3 <strsep+12>: je     0x7fff915c1007 <strsep+64>
0x00007fff915c0fd5 <strsep+14>: mov    %r8,%r10
0x00007fff915c0fd8 <strsep+17>: jmp    0x7fff915c0fe4 <strsep+29>
0x00007fff915c0fda <strsep+19>: inc    %rdx
0x00007fff915c0fdd <strsep+22>: test   %al,%al
0x00007fff915c0fdf <strsep+24>: jne    0x7fff915c0fee <strsep+39>
0x00007fff915c0fe1 <strsep+26>: mov    %r9,%r10
0x00007fff915c0fe4 <strsep+29>: mov    (%r10),%cl
0x00007fff915c0fe7 <strsep+32>: lea    0x1(%r10),%r9
0x00007fff915c0feb <strsep+36>: mov    %rsi,%rdx
0x00007fff915c0fee <strsep+39>: mov    (%rdx),%al
0x00007fff915c0ff0 <strsep+41>: cmp    %cl,%al
0x00007fff915c0ff2 <strsep+43>: jne    0x7fff915c0fda <strsep+19>
0x00007fff915c0ff4 <strsep+45>: xor    %edx,%edx
0x00007fff915c0ff6 <strsep+47>: test   %cl,%cl
0x00007fff915c0ff8 <strsep+49>: je     0x7fff915c1001 <strsep+58>
0x00007fff915c0ffa <strsep+51>: movb   $0x0,(%r10)
0x00007fff915c0ffe <strsep+55>: mov    %r9,%rdx
0x00007fff915c1001 <strsep+58>: mov    %rdx,(%rdi)
0x00007fff915c1004 <strsep+61>: mov    %r8,%rax
0x00007fff915c1007 <strsep+64>: pop    %rbp
0x00007fff915c1008 <strsep+65>: retq
```

Edit: 
string.h is definitely being included, there's a system-wide include file that includes it, but just to make sure I tried adding it this specific file. `-D_BSD_SOURCE=1` is one of the compiler options added automatically, so that is happening. There is also a compiler option `-D_ISOC99_SOURCE=1` by default. I tried adding `-std=gnu99` (my compiler, llvm-gcc 4.2, doesn't like `-std=gnu90`), but it did not fix it. I'm getting the following compiler errors:

Here are the compiler warnings that I get for this file:

```
ow_alias.c: In function 'ReadAliasFile':
ow_alias.c:40: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getline'
ow_alias.c:48: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strsep'
ow_alias.c:48: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
ow_alias.c:64: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
ow_alias.c: In function 'FS_dir_entry_aliased':
ow_alias.c:177: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Second Edit:
After doing a little more digging (thanks for the `gcc -E | grep strsep` tip!), I found the problem was with a compiler flag `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L`. This compiler flag was blocking the definition of strsep, making the compiler make an implicit declaration. I removed this from the configure script and everything seems to be working fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does the offending compilation unit `#include <string.h>`? If so, what does `cc -E | grep strsep` show `strsep` to be declared as?

Comment: Using `gcc -I./module/owlib/src/include -I/opt/local/include -I./src/include -E module/owlib/src/c/ow_alias.c | grep strsep`, I get strsep declared as `char *strsep(char **, const char *);`, which seems right. But in the full Make process I get the compiler warnings in my edit above...

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure that `string.h` is included.

If that's already being done, you'll need to also define a feature test macro to enable the declaration of `strsep()`.  Adding `-D_GNU_SOURCE` or `-D_BSD_SOURCE` should do the trick.  However, you might want to look into how you have things configured right now - `_BSD_SOURCE` is usually enabled by default. Perhaps you're telling gcc to compile with `-std=c90` or `-std=c99`, which will turn off many feature test macros. Use `-std=gnu90` or `-std=gnu99` instead.

Are you seeing warnings such as "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast" or "implicit declaration of function"?

Comment: +1; the disassembly shows that the compiler thinks `strsep` returns a 32-bit value (e.g. an int).

Comment: This seems to be on the right track, but I'm still having trouble making it work. See my edit to the original question - I tried `-std=c99` and `D_BSD_SOURCE` is already happening. The compiler warnings confirm what's going on is that the compiler thinks strsep is returning an int, not a size_t pointer.